# C# keeping track of daily tasks done

Tags: c#, mongodb

i'm trying to figure out a way to optimize the way i count daily actions done.
I have a software that runs a bunch of "task executors", which all have an id.
Each task executor logs all tasks done in a local mongo database, with executor id, task type and epoch timestamp.
 In order to count daily actions of specific types for each of the task executors, i'm querying mongo to count logs of the action type, for the task executor id and with an epoch > now minus 24 hours.
This is done atleast once per minute by each task executor, but it's quite inefficient, when the collections are huge(100k-1mil).
How else could i count how many of a specific task, each executor id has done within the last 24 hours?

A simpler way to put it, is how would you keep count of daily activity in any application, that doesn't run 24/7? And then being able to access that count very frequently.

Any advice would be GREATLY appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Maybe create a table containing aggregated results? I don't think I fully understood what you wanted though :/

Comment: I rewrote the question, hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: Sounds like you need to [add an index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/).

Comment: If I were you, I would count the tasks every hour and store the intermediate results.  Then, for one day, you will just collect the 24 entries and sum the result.

Comment: I do have indexes in the collection, but there's over 10k task executors running simultaneously, an they're each making this CountDocument query every 40-60 seconds.

Comment: Are your indexes tuned to this particular task though? "I have indexes" is very different to "I have an index for this particular query"

Comment: @Nick That's a great idea, I'm sure that'd help a lot. Thanks!

Comment: @Liam I actually don't think my indexes are anywhere near perfect. I'm not experienced with mongo at all, but i found it to be fast enough for my usecase, much more so than other databases i've tried. I just went to Compass, hit create indexes, chose the fields and chose ascending. Performance was better and i din't look further into it.

Comment: Your question and your comment above contradict each other, you state "it's quite inefficient, when the collections are huge" but then you say " i found it to be fast enough for my usecase", so is it fast enough or too slow? What do you mean by inefficient? Your comment suggests that you don't know how indexes works, I'd suggest you read up on these, they are fundamental to how mongo works. Don't fall into the "Mongo is like SQL but faster" trap. For mongo you need to tune your queries to get performance on large datasets when querying the data in a document

Comment: @Liam Man relax.... I never said mongo wasn't performing well enough for me. It's great at a ton of other stuff my software uses it for. I'm just wondering if it's viable to do count document queries based on 3 fields, in collections will potentially millions of documents and doing these counting queries 250+ times per second, all from within the same application.

Comment: @Liam I'm happy to hear that. That's the first time you're saying it btw.

Comment: Why'd you delete your comment?

Comment: Because it's not entirely true, the answer is it depends. It depends on lots and lots of things, including the machine it's on, the disk speed, number of hosts, sharding, fragmentation, network speed, etc etc.. Can mongo handle this, yes, can your server handle this, you'll need to test it to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would count the tasks every hour and store the intermediate results. Then, for one day, you will just collect the 24 entries and sum the result.